# Create a bash function to launch according to file types

Tags: bash

I'm thinking about emulating `xdg-open` with a bash function like the following:

```
launch() {
    case "$1" in
        *.pdf) mupdf-gl "$1" &> /dev/null & ;;
        *.mp4) mpv "$1" &> /dev/null & ;;
        *.mkv) mpv "$1" &> /dev/null & ;;
        *) echo "Cannot launch \"$1\"";;
    esac
}
```

The reason I'm not using `xdg-open` directly is because I keep my configuration files updated with git and I use them for three different machines. So, I can't figure out how to keep a single `xdg-open` config files. Instead I am just going with the aforementioned approach.

So, my question is, **is there any possible downside that I'll be facing if I take this approach?** I don't care about the required apps not being installed cause the first thing I do is installed all the required apps in any new installation, so I'm covered there.

Comment: Regarding `git`, you keep 3 different `xdg-open` config files in your repository, and when you first clone the repo to a particular machine, you create a symlink to the appropriate file. The symlink remains valid across future Git pulls.

Comment: I didn't know xdg-open has a config file. Where is it? I even read archwiki on it.

Comment: I don't know; I thought from your question that you were referring to such config files in your reason for not using `xdg-open`.

Comment: Oh no. I was saying that I use config files for keeping all machines in sync. And I can't find out if I can use config files for xdg-open.

Comment: Ah, ok. Also, `xdg-open` appears to reply on URL protocols, not file extensions, for choosing which application to use to open a file.

Comment: This might help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251054/how-does-the-xdg-open-command-know-which-application-to-use-to-open-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > is there any possible downside that I'll be facing if I take this approach?

Yes.

The file extensions may not represent the content. As an example:

```
ljm@verlaine[tmp]$ file 0006.jpg 
0006.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 663x663, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=5, manufacturer=Nikon, model=LS-40], baseline, precision 8, 3863x2432, frames 3
ljm@verlaine[tmp]$ mv 0006.jpg 0006.pdf
ljm@verlaine[tmp]$ file 0006.pdf 
0006.pdf: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 663x663, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=5, manufacturer=Nikon, model=LS-40], baseline, precision 8, 3863x2432, frames 3
ljm@verlaine[tmp]$
```

You now have a `.pdf` file, with the content of a JPEG file.